# How to get a PHP iteration variable in an external jquery.js file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm writing a PHP program that displays a user's to do list.  What I have is basically an unordered list that has a checkbox that, when checked, will allow the user to mark a list item as done (i.e give the text a strikethrough).  Here's the code I have for the list

```
echo '<ul>';

for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++){

       $text = "This is item number " . $i;
       $complete = 'No';
       $order = 'This item is to be done #' . $i;

       echo '<li id = '. $i . '>';

    echo 'Item complete? <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />';
    echo '<span id = ' . $i . ' onLoad="crossOut()">Item: ' . $text . ' Complete? ' .$complete . '&nbsp&nbspWhen to do Item: ' . $order . '</span>';
    echo '</li>';

       }

echo '</ul>';


}
```

And here's the jquery function I'm using

```
$(document).ready(function crossOut(){
    $("#checkbox").change(function crossOutText(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#liID").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        }
    })
})
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to pass the list ID from the PHP to the jquery function, in an external JS file, so that whenever a user checks an item it marks that list item done and puts a strikethrough on the text of that list item.  I'm new to using jquery and any help that anyone is willing to give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parents("li").css("text-decoration", "line-through");
            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ strike through the parent list item.
        }
    })
})
```

---

Here is a better way using a CSS class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").change(function(){
        $(this).parents("li").toggleClass('strike', this.checked)
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ strike through the parent list item.
    })
})
```

CSS:

```css
.strike {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/unmLd/

---

Disclamer: 

<sub>I changed `#checkbox` to `input:checkbox` in both example because you **cannot** have multiple elements with the same ID!

Try using a class instead.</sub>

Also, **remove** the `crossout()` part of your code... It does not do anything and might throw an error on your page...

Comment: I tried testing the second method in my code but for some reason it's not working.  Probably something simple that I've done that I'm missing.  That's exactly what I'm looking for though.

Comment: Happy to help @AaronKlassen ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "line-through");
        }else{
            $(this).parent().css("text-decoration", "none");
        }
    });
});
</script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++){
        $text = "This is item number " . $i;
        $complete = 'No';
        $order = 'This item is to be done #' . $i;
        echo '<li id = '. $i . '>';
        echo 'Item complete? <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />';
        echo '<span id = ' . $i . '>Item: ' . $text . ' Complete? ' .$complete . '&nbsp&nbspWhen to do Item: ' . $order . '</span>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```